# I need a Pop up with description when i click an image

Tags: jquery

i need a pop up with description of an image when i click that image. How can this be done? Is there any plugin in wordpress that can do this?

Answer (score 1):

WordPress comes with bundled Thickbox script, that you can load using [`wp_enqueue_script()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script#Default_scripts_included_with_WordPress). See [Thickbox documentation](http://jquery.com/demo/thickbox/) for details on what it can do and how to configure it.